# How to enable access to local files only for one script in tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tampermonkey

I'm using tampermonkey to build chrome extensions and I would like to split one extension in multiples files. So I'm thinking to do this way:

In chrome settings, grant access to local files for tampermonkey, and then the extension in tampermonkey will only contains requires in header to import and execute js files from my hard drive.

But what now ? All tampermonkey extensions have access to my hard drive ? It seems very unsafe, I have lot of extensions that I didn't made myself, and they could read my hard drive and post data anywhere ! How to enable access to local files only for one script in tampermonkey ?

Comment: You should create an extension instead of using tampermonkey. That is the safest way to solve this issue. See [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) to learn how to create an extension.

Comment: sure but the disavantage with that is I can't choose extensions execution order right ?

Comment: If you declare a content script with `run_at: 'document_start'`, then you can be pretty sure that it runs before your tampermonkey scripts, because tampermonkey always has the overhead of asynchronously loading the scripts from a database, whereas the Chrome extension's content script is immediately executed by Chrome.

Comment: BTW userscripts aren't extensions, so it'd be reasonable if you don't mix the terms.

Comment: @RobW my script, on local files, only worked after `@run-at document_start` or `@run-at document-body` (this other tip I found [here](https://forum.tampermonkey.net/viewtopic.php?t=1185#p4255)). @sylvain1264 I think you could make a request to the tampermonkey development team? btw, I think [it is](https://forum.tampermonkey.net/viewtopic.php?t=274) open-source, so you can start right away and contribute :)